# Creating tab equivalent with CSS, first entry on same line

Tags: html, css, web, space

I'm trying to do something that is very classic in word processing, but apparently less common in CSS. I'm putting movie info into a website, and want to format information like so:

**Director:**    John Smith
**Cast:**          Person A
                   Person B
                   Person C
**Writer:**       James Smith


Yea, so how would I go about doing that? The issue is that I'm trying to format the titles (director, cast, etc) differently from the regular text.  Here's what I have right now:

```
<div>
    <h3>Director: <span style="font-weight:300;">John Carney</span></h3>               <h3>Writer: <span style="font-weight:300;">John Carney</span></h3>
    <h3>Cast: <span style="font-weight:300;">Keira Knightley<br>Mark
    Ruffalo</span></h3>
  </div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about basing it around a [description list](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists#Description_lists) as @vch suggested?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dt2v7zys/2/

```
<dl>
    <dt>Director:</dt>
    <dd>John Carney</dd>

    <dt>Writer:</dt>
    <dd>John Carney</dd>

    <dt>Cast:</dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li>Keira Knightley</li>
            <li>Mark Ruffalo</li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Styled using...

```
dt {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 4px;
}
dd {
    margin-left: 88px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

Alternatively, a `dt` may have multiple `dd` values that define/describe it, e.g.:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dt2v7zys/1/

```
<dl> 
    <dt>Director:</dt>
    <dd>John Carney</dd> 

    <dt>Writer:</dt>
    <dd>John Carney</dd> 

    <!-- note the multiple values for a single dt -->
    <dt>Cast:</dt>
    <dd>Keira Knightley</dd>
    <dd>Mark Ruffalo</dd>

    <dt>Producer:</dt>
    <dd>Another Guy</dd> 
</dl>
```

Comment: This does not format the content as described in the question. There is no difference in text style, and there are bullets that are not present in the description.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - I provided 3 different ways to format the content (including one that showed text styles, in a comment on another answer: http://jsfiddle.net/dt2v7zys/3/). The use of an unordered list is of course optional ("the are bullets not present in the description") which are a better alternative than `br` to separate items. If an unordered list isn't desired, the second demo (multiple `dd`) can be used.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a definition list: `<dl>, <dt>, <dd>`. There are some examples, including css [here](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/).

Comment: Yea, I've looked at those, but then the first word doesn't appear after the "definition" it appears in the line below and I want the first word in line with the "definition" and then all others lined up below it.

Comment: Out of the box, yes. But see the code below from @tim. If you look at his jsfiddle, you'll see he's used css to make it appear in the format you're after.

Comment: yup, saw that! Thanks @Tim Medora and all others!

Comment: Side comment(can only post each 90 mins): How do I make the <dt> have the same style as <h3>?

Comment: You can style the `dt` any way you want, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/dt2v7zys/3/. Or if you have a style already defined for `h3`, you can copy it to the `dt` selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<div>
  <h3><span>Director:</span>John Carney</h3>
  <h3><span>Cast:</span>Keira Knightley<br>Mark Ruffalo</h3>
  <h3><span>Writer:</span>James Smith</h3>
</div>
```

And then in your stylesheet:

```
h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

h3 span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that html you could use the following css:

```
h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
h3 span {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Yea, that'd be cleaner for the style, Thanks. Big thing here is the alignment though.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an array (matrix) of data, so the most logical markup uses an HTML `table` element. It is also the simplest from the viewpoint of styling. Minimally you just need to set the alignment of header cells to left (instead of the default centering) and vertical alignment of cells to top (instead of the default middle):

```
<style>
th { text-align: left }
th, td { vertical-align: top }
</style>
<table>
<tr><th>Director: <td>John Smith
<tr><th rowspan=3>Cast:<td>Person A
<tr><td>Person B
<tr><td>Person C
<tr><th>Writer: <td>James Smith 
</table>
```

By default, `th` elements are rendered in bold. The distinction between normal and bold (`font-weight: normal` and `font-weight: bold`) is the only reliable way of making a difference in font weight, since most fonts have no other weights. This means that for most fonts, `font-weight: 300` causes normal weight typeface to be used.